# Expected unqualified-id before "for" Arduino

Tags: arduino

Este script me da un error llamado expected unqualified-id before "for".
Este es el script:

```
const int LED=9;
int i=0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for(i=0;i<255;i++)
    analogWrite(LED,i);
    delay(10);
  }

  for (i = 255; i > 0; i--) {
    analogWrite(LED,i);
    delay(10);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código observo dos problemas:

- El primer `for` no tiene llave de apertura. Si compila es porque se te ha olvidado indicarlo al copiar el código.
- El primer `for` itera en el rango [0-254] mientras que el segundo lo hace en el rango [255-1]. Da la impresión que el segundo rango no es correcto.

Si este es el error la solución sería:

```
for (i = 254; i >= 0; i--) {
  analogWrite(LED,i);
  delay(10);
}
```

Un saludo